# How do I install and play the BrettspielWelt client?

Tags: 12.04, games, client

BrettspielWelt is a board game client available to download to play board games with other players on the internet. (http://www.brettspielwelt.de/?nation=en)

I am completely new to Ubuntu having only just downloaded and installed it on my computer and still don't understand all the basics.

So my problem is that having downloaded the BrettspielWelt client, I extracted it to a folder, and set permissions for the start.sh file to open as an executable.

Now when I click the start.sh to open, it should start the BrettspielWelt client but nothing happens!

So can someone help me please? As I have no idea why it didn't, although I was wondering is it something to do with java?

Also if there are any board game fans out there, get BrettspielWelt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Readme.txt states

> You must have java installed on your computer which is up to date. (1.4-1.6)

To install java, follow the [Ubuntu Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)

Many applications don't work with the OpenJDK java, you might have to get the Oracle Version

edit: it does at least start with openjdk!